# Send PDF file made with PDFkit to the client for display

Tags: node.js, reactjs, http, express, pdfkit

I'm having trouble with the mental model of what I'm trying to achieve, I might be completely wrong and apologize if that's the case.

I have a full-stack app that I'm building that deals with budgeting products, what I have is a React client that sends a "budget" object with all the relevant information on a post request to my server and it looks like:

```
let budget = {
  name: 'John Doe',
  phone: 12345,
  email: 'johndoe@gmail.com'
  cart: [Object with name, quantity, and price of product, etc, another object that represents another product],
  subTotal: 100,
  tax: 12,
  total: 112
}
```

I send that data to my NodeJS/Express server in which I have PDFKit to help me create the PDF, and I want to send it back to the client so that the user can download/print/view his budget in PDF format, code in the server looks like this

```
const pdf = require('pdfkit');
const fs = require('fs');

exports.makeBudgetPDF = (req, res) => {

  let myDoc = new pdf;
  myDoc.pipe(res);
  myDoc.font('Times-Roman')
       .fontSize(12)
       .text(`this is a test budget`);
  myDoc.end();
  res.setHeader('access-control-allow-origin', '*');
  res.status(200);
}
```

That's all good, I'm sending back to the client with the response of the request but I don't know how to display it from there, I get a data object(I'm using axios for the requests on the client side) that looks like this and I have absolutely no idea what to do with it

```
Object
data:
"%PDF-1.3↵%����↵5 0 obj↵<<↵/Type /Page↵/Parent 1 0 R↵/MediaBox [0 0 612 792]↵/Contents 3 0 R↵/Resources 4 0 R↵>>↵endobj↵4 0 obj↵<<↵/ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI]↵/Font <<↵/F2 6 0 R↵>>↵>>↵endobj↵7 0 obj↵<<↵/Producer (PDFKit)↵/Creator (PDFKit)↵/CreationDate (D:20170623192634Z)↵>>↵endobj↵6 0 obj↵<<↵/Type /Font↵/BaseFont /Times-Roman↵/Subtype /Type1↵/Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding↵>>↵endobj↵2 0 obj↵<<↵/Type /Catalog↵/Pages 1 0 R↵>>↵endobj↵1 0 obj↵<<↵/Type /Pages↵/Count 1↵/Kids [5 0 R]↵>>↵endobj↵3 0 obj↵<<↵/Length 200↵/Filter /FlateDecode↵>>↵stream↵x��O9NA�����.OK#$Ȑ:C0G6��?Y�j�@�ڲ�\�g=H>є������=��R(�B�4�S��㫒(��|��P4��OT+��s8*�!�&�f�V
��3\�g�&]`X1+��슯$�pe������bK��jK��n�?����^��m8��8s�q2K�Jv$;JS}O�����'��~.��T�↵endstream↵endobj↵xref↵0 8↵0000000000 65535 f ↵0000000448 00000 n ↵0000000399 00000 n ↵0000000505 00000 n ↵0000000119 00000 n ↵0000000015 00000 n ↵0000000300 00000 n ↵0000000208 00000 n ↵trailer↵<<↵/Size 8↵/Root 2 0 R↵/Info 7 0 R↵>>↵startxref↵777↵%%EOF↵"

headers:
Object

request:
XMLHttpRequest

status:
200

statusText:
"OK"
```

I've been researching a lot about it but can't seem to find an answer

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I have the same issue. Fetching the file directly from the node server gives me the pdf. Calling the restful api from reactjs gives me the jibberish you wrote last.

Comment: Kind of late, but I got the same question. How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with PDFKit but have been working with PDFMake. 
You likely need to set the content type of your response in the headers, similar to:

```
res.writeHead(200, {
  'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
  'Content-disposition': 'attachment;filename=[your-filename].pdf',
  'Content-Length': response.ContentLength
});
```

This will force a download in the user's browser. 
Swap out [your-filename] with whatever you want the file to be named. `response.ContentLength` is the PDF buffer size from a previous callback, not shown in my example. Replace it with the content size of your document.

[edit] And just remembering, I had issues piping to res. You might end up writing your PDF to a buffer and then calling:

```
res.end(Buffer.from([your pdf buffer]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe old question but I was having similar issue and found the answer.

First of all when you create new pdf use:

```
const myDoc = pdf();
```

Code that worked for me looked like that:

```
  const pdfName = "generated.pdf";
  const generatedPdfPath = path.join("dist", "temp", pdfName); // depending where you want your pdf

  const doc = new pdf();
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
  res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", `inline; filename=${pdfName}`);

  doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(generatedPdfPath));
  doc.pipe(res);

  doc.text('some text or anything else you want');
  // in my case I was adding multiple images and it also worked fined

  doc.end();
```